# mysql Incorrect string value: '\xE9 M.'

Tags: mysql

I have a function "lr_encrypt" that use AES_ENCRYPT to encrypt the sensitive data in MySQL Table.

```
drop function if exists lr_encrypt;
delimiter $$
create function lr_encrypt(p_text varchar(1000) character set utf8)
   returns varbinary(200)
begin

    declare l_word varchar(300) default '';
    declare l_key_length int default 512;

    select word
      into l_word  
      from lr_words;

    return aes_encrypt(p_text, SHA2(l_word,l_key_length));

end
$$
```

Now when I use this function I get the following error:

Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xE9 M.' for column 'p_text' at row 8659

I checked the records 8659 and it keep the following value:

[image]

Please help fix above function !

Comment: Which encoding is used in table itself for fields in question?

Comment: DEFAULT_CHAR_SET for this field is utf8mb4, CHARACTER_SET_NAME is empty